# How do i self host next js 13.4 with app router using cpanel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, cpanel, next.js13

I am using the latest app router on next but cant seem to deploy using app router. I have used the server js file i used on page router and its not working. I replaced the server.js with the code from output:"standalone" and it is not working as well.
I also deployed on vercel and it works there ,how do i self host next js 13.4

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any server feature, then just build and export it as static website and then host it as if it was static website, otherwise you will need hosting provider that supports nodejs, for example I have hosted it on ec2 [instance](https://www.assignmenthelp.net/). It has tones of microservices, one single app is split into many micro nextjs apps. since we need both static and dynamic feature as well, We have to supports more than 10 million pages which was not supported by nextjs natively. However I think you don't need all this complexity so just go with any hosting that allow you to install nodejs or they provide natively. You might need pm2 tool too.